# “Do you want to format it?” message when opening partition

Tags: windows, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I can't open a partition on my PC that contains my projects and all my source code, since the PC powered off incorrectly. When I open it I found this message:

> Do you want to format it?

The partition doesn't read disk total size nor used size.

Once I've found an application that makes an image of damaged partition or damaged card memory and repaired by a similar problem, but I forgot its name.

What should I do to access my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testdisk should help you out in your situation, what probably happened was that the partition table got corrupted or something similar

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

has all the instructions you need